# Creating an array with variable size in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to c++ and I am trying to create a function to return a value from an array. Here are the instructions for the assignment:

> In this exercise, you will create a function to return a value from
>   an array. If the index is out of range, return 0.
>
> **Function Name**:   read01
>
> **Parameters**:  (data,size,index)
>
> 1)  *data*: An array of constant int's
>
> 2)  *size*: An int, the number of slots in data
>
> 3)  *index*: An int, the desired position in data
>
> **Return Value**:  An int, the value of position index in data, or 0.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
int read01(int data[], int size, int index){
    return data[index];
}
```

I know how to do the "if" statement so that's not an issue, but where I am confused is how to define the size parameter as the size of `data[]`. I know you cannot put "`int size`" into the data parameter like so, "`int data[int size]`", but I cannot figure out another way to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should format the assignment as a blockquote, not as code (since it is not code).

Comment: `int data[],` is correct already

Comment: @M.M then what's the point of having a size parameter if it's not being used to define the size of data?

Comment: Are you asking how to set the length of the array via the size? Something like, size = 4, so The array size should be of length 4?

Comment: @Sailanarmo exactly

Comment: @BrockMorrison the size of data is defined in the calling function , the point of the `size` parameter is so that `read01` knows how big the array is that it is referencing

Comment: the calling code will look something like `int main()  { int x[5];   read01(x, 5, 3); }`. The array does not have variable size (your title does not reflect the requirements of the assignment)

Comment: @M.M I do not get to determine how big size is. This is being run on a program where as soon as I submit the code there is a unit test being done in the background, therefore the size of `int data[]' needs to be user defined.

Comment: @BrockMorrison the "user" defining the size is not your function. The array is created outside your function and your function receives a view on it, and the length of the view is the `size` parameter. Your function does not create or resize any arrays,  it reads a value out of an array that already exists

Comment: @BrockMorrison see this link. It is a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851181/define-array-then-change-its-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer would be

```
#include <iostream>
int read01(const int data[], int size, int index) {
    if ( index >= size ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return data[ index ];
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had it returning 0 outside of the if statements and it kept throwing me an error. Thank you @mychsmit!

Answer (score 4):

We can define size of array like:

```cpp
int Data[5]; //here 5 is size of array or

int Data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //In this number of elements describe the size.
```

To get size of array use(standard c way: to get size of static array):

```
sizeof(Data) / sizeof(Data[0]);
```

you can also try `Distance` method to get size:

```
distance(begin(Data),end(Data));
```

Edit: You cant make array user defined because size of array needs to compile at compile time. So options are you can use vectors or pointers.

But in case of c++ use `std::vector` instead of arrays:

```
std::vector<int> vc;
vc.push_back(1);
vc.push_back(2);
vc.push_back(3);
std::cout << vc.size() << std::endl; // it will print 3(size of vector)
```

If you wanna define size dynamically then try something like:

```
int size;   
std::cin >> size;
int *A = new int[size];//dynamically assign memory to pointer A 
/*your code here*/
delete[] A;
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: I don't see how any of this answers the OP's question.

Comment: @user4581301 if i get the question he wanna define size of array or i am missing something

Comment: @Preet I am asking how to set the length of the array via the size parameter... so when the the size parameter is defined as size = 4, the array size should be 4. As I stated in the comments above, this is being entered into a unit test where I have no idea what is being used as parameters in my code.

Comment: @BrockMorrison you cannot change the size of an array, nor does the assignment appear to be asking you to do so. My suspicion is you are expected to test if  `index` is less than `size` ( and return the value in `data` at `index`) or return 0 if `index` is not less than `size`. Also watch out for "data: An array of constant int's" because you have not specified `data` to be constant in `int read01(int data[], int size, int index)`. Read up on the `const` keyword.

Comment: sorry to miss the concept, Actually array size needs to define at compile time so you cant change it as @user4581301 said. if you wanna do this you can use std::vector