# Create an array when the size is a variable not a constant

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Here is the program:

```
int siz = 0;
int n = 0;
FILE* picture;

picture = fopen("test.jpg", "r");
fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_END);
siz = ftell(picture);

char Sbuf[siz];
fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_SET); //Going to the beginning of the file
while (!feof(picture)) {
    n = fread(Sbuf, sizeof(char), siz, picture);
    /* ... do stuff with the buffer ... */
    /* memset(Sbuf, 0, sizeof(Sbuf)); 
}
```

I need to read the file size. 
I know for sure that this code compiled on another compiler.
How to correctly declare `siz` correctly so that the code compiles?

Comment: `std::vector` is purposed for that.

Comment: [`new`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-and-delete-operators-in-cpp-for-dynamic-memory/) and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) are your friend in these types of situations.

Comment: I assume you are using Sbuf as an array with bytes of the image, wouldn't using `unsigned char` instead of the `char` be better?

Comment: @Chipster `new` is probably not the OP's friend in these types of situations.

Comment: @L.F. Fair enough. My thought was it was a way to create a variable length array if they really needed an array type thing and couldn't settle for something like a `std::vector`. I fully agree there are much better options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define array, then change its size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851181/define-array-then-change-its-size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no proper way to do this, as a program with any variable length array is [ill-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22180312/10957435).

An alternative, so to speak, to a variable length array is a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<char> Sbuf;

Sbuf.push_back(someChar);
```

Of course, I should mention that if you are using `char` specifically, [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) might work well for you. [Here are some examples of how to use `std::string`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstring-class-in-c/), if you're interested.

The other alternative to a variable length array is the [`new` operator/keyword](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-and-delete-operators-in-cpp-for-dynamic-memory/), although `std::vector` is usually better if you can make use of it:

```
char* Sbuf = new char[siz];

delete [] Sbuf;
```

However, this solution does risk memory leaks. Thus, `std::vector` is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create an array using `new` keyword:

```cpp
char* Sbuf; // declare a char pointer Sbuf
Sbuf = new char[siz]; // new keyword creates an array and returns the adress of that array

delete Sbuf; // you have to remember to deallocate your memory when you are done
```

Better, more standard compatible approach would be to use smart pointers

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<char[]> Sbuf = std::make_unique<char[]>(siz);
```