# Why can't I use push_back in this scenario?

Tags: c++

I think what I am doing in the code is legal, yet it shows runtime error. Why?

```
int main() {
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    while(q--)
    {
        int n, start;
        vector<int> adj[n];
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                int x;
                cin>>x;
                //if(x==1) start = i;
                adj[i].push_back(x);
            }
        }

    }
    //code
    return 0;
}
```

Runtime Error:
Runtime Error Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

Comment: First, arrays must have a constant size in C++. Second, `n` is not initialized anywhere.

Comment: You make a variable `n` with no value, then try to create an array of that. Super undefined behaviour

Comment: Part of the reason is that [your code is ill-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367539/10957435).

Comment: You should use the highest warning level when you compile. gcc warning `warning: ‘n’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid c++ code:

```
vector<int> adj[n];
```

It may work on gcc and some other compilers, because of an extension they may have for c99 style array. 
If you turn on compiler warnings you can detect those. [Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kVNySzJw5wlpg10o)

As @Prakasht pointed out in their answer, there is also uninitialized variable `n` in the code. Using `n` is an undefined behavior anything can happen.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't initialise `n`. Just initialise `n` before declaring your vector. Something like `n=10` or `cin>>n`.

Comment: While I agree that's part of the problem, it's not the only problem.

Comment: Correct! I used to code exactly like this in my starting days.:p

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear. Please see my comment on the original post. It will explain another major problem.

Comment: Thanks @Chipster. I also found a nice article [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Kills-The-VLA). Learning new things is great!

Comment: @TamalMaity No. This question may help other people in the future.