# Strange C++ 2D array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays

**EDIT**

Thanks to @crashmstr, he showed the error.
I forgot to add `const` to `ROW` and `COL`, VLAs were the reason for the 'errors'.

This is literally all the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int ROW = 3;
    int COL = 4;

    int arr[ROW][COL] = { { 5 } };

    for(int row = 0; row < ROW; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < COL; col++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[row][col] << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

This is the output:

```
5   4199120 4201168 0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0
```

And this was my expected output:

```
5   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0
```

My Question: Why is this happening? When you initialize a 1D array `int arr[3] { 5 };` the first element is set to 5 and everything else to 0, but when I do the 'same' with the 2D array I get this

Comment: `int arr[ROW][COL]` is not standard C++ unless `ROW` and `COL` are constant expressions.

Comment: My understanding is that only the first element is initialized because only one value was supplied; all other elements are not initialized.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's the same situation with `int arr[3] { 5 }`. why all are zero in this case?

Comment: @crashmstr I... I just have no words for myself. Thank you, I totally overlooked that!

Comment: @mangusta In your example you have a legal array.  In the OP's example they have a VLA which is not legal and how it is initialized is implementation defined.

Comment: @MaratIsaw Make sure to turn on your compiler warnings!

Comment: @0x5453 Yeah, now I know why warnings are so important

Comment: In light of your edit, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57367473/10957435