# Make a loop to append in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have below code and i would like to make loop for appending to the graph!

Example:

```
    graph[1].push_back(make_pair(2, 3)); 
    graph[2].push_back(make_pair(4, 8)); 
    graph[3].push_back(make_pair(3, 7)); 
    ...
    graph[6].push_back(make_pair(5, 8));
```

To:

```
// is there any better way!!!
int n,a,b;

    vector< pair<int,int> > graph[n+1]; 


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> a >> b;

    graph[n].push_back(make_pair(a, b)); 
}
```

My main Function...

```
int main() 
{ 
    // n is number nodes
    int n = 6; 

    vector< pair<int,int> > graph[n+1]; 

    // create undirected graph 
    // first edge 
    graph[1].push_back(make_pair(2, 3)); 
    graph[2].push_back(make_pair(1, 3)); 

    // second edge 
    graph[2].push_back(make_pair(3, 4)); 
    graph[3].push_back(make_pair(2, 4)); 

    // third edge 
    graph[2].push_back(make_pair(6, 2)); 
    graph[6].push_back(make_pair(2, 2)); 

    // fourth edge 
    graph[4].push_back(make_pair(6, 6)); 
    graph[6].push_back(make_pair(4, 6)); 

    // fifth edge 
    graph[5].push_back(make_pair(6, 5)); 
    graph[6].push_back(make_pair(5, 5)); 

    cout << myFunction(graph, n); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Would anyone help me to fix the issues! Is there any better way to solve the loop?

Comment: What's the point of having one `vector` for each `pair` ?

Comment: Once i get the all input from command line i would like to do loop! My loop does not seems to be work with this one:
```
    graph[n].push_back(make_pair(a, b)); 
```

Comment: `vector< pair<int,int> > graph[n+1];` [is not a good thing to do in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57367473/10957435).

Comment: Ok! But is it the right way to pushback into loop?     graph[n].push_back(make_pair(a, b));

Comment: Are you trying to set the size of the vector here `    vector< pair<int,int> > graph[n+1]; ` and then want to push all pairs to it?

Comment: @Joe See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57367473/10957435) of why declaring `graph` this way is wrong, array access is 0-based, meaning the first item in your array is actually `graph[0]`, and there is no `graph[6]`. So just subtract 1 from all of your indices (and fix the other really bad bug).

---

> Is there any better way to solve the loop!

It is unclear to me what the formula for creating a pair here would entail, but I can tell you that you can put most things into a loop like this:

```
for(i =0;i<6-1 /* or whatever size you want */;i++) {
    graph[i].push_back(make_pair(/*Not sure what goes in here */)); 
    graph[i+1].push_back(make_pair(/* but it should be a start */));
        // also, this is why we do size - 1, since we are adding 1 to i here
}
```