# For Loop Executing only once in cpp

Tags: c++

Hey am trying to run this code but the for loop executes only once. 
Removing the line cout< fixes the problem but I need the ans to be precise to 15 decimal places.
here's the code

```
int n,i;
cin>>n;
double a[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    cin>>a[i];
    a[i]=(a[i]/100);
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(15)<<a[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    cout<<a[i];
}
```

Comment: It works for me! Are you sure you're compiling the right file?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57367473/10957435

Comment: Shameless plug -- but Well Done `:)`

Answer (score 2):

#### First things first

Use of variable length arrays (VLAs) is not standard C++. It is supported by some compilers as an extension. If you are allowed to use `std::vector,` use

```
std::vector<double> a(n);
```

If you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, use

```
double* a = new double[n];
```

and make sure to use

```
delete [] a;
```

before the end of the funtion.

#### Suggestion to help you diagnose the problem

Add appropriate prompts before entering data and messages to indicate what was read.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout << "Enter number for a[" << i << "]: ";
    cin>>a[i];
    a[i]=(a[i]/100);

    // Make sure to add endl at the very end.
    cout<< "Value of a[" << i << "]: " << fixed << setprecision(15) << a[i] << endl;
}
```