# Allocating dynamically an array of Strings in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic

I have allocated a string array in CPP with initial size and I need to dynamically resize it based on a counter.

This the initialization statement: string buffer[10];
I need to resize it based on a counter.
Is there a realloc function in cpp?

Comment: No, there isn't. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::vector`, for a more complete explanation of how this needs to be done.

Comment: C has a realloc but you would need to use the malloc or calloc C function to allocate the array in the first place.   Using C functions is for backwards compatibility only and it isn't best practice for a new C++ program to use them.  The comment about using std::vector is good advice.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Of _course_ there's a `realloc` function in c++.  You can't use it to reallocate an automatic variable (a variable allocated on the stack, as OP appears to be doing it) but you could definitely allocate an array of strings, and then reallocate it.  (It's messier than just using a `std::vector`, but OP's instructor may be teaching the old-fashioned messy way first, before showing the easy, modern way.)

Comment: @DaveM. -- try to use malloc and realloc with `std::string`s, and see how well it works out for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an array when the size is a variable not a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367473/create-an-array-when-the-size-is-a-variable-not-a-constant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like a linked list such as `std::vector` or `std::list` to do so, here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  list<string> buffer;
  int count = 0;

  while (true)
  {
    string s;

    cin >> s;

    if (s._Equal("exit"))
      break;

    buffer.push_back(s);
    count++;
  }

  cout << endl << endl << "We have a total of " << count << " string(s):";

  for (auto i = buffer.begin(); i != buffer.end(); i++)
    cout << endl << "- " << (*i).c_str();

  cout << endl << endl;
  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

link: [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
std::vector is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays.

Comment: Removing several problems, adding IO checking, and utilizing standard-defined member functions and/or operators (wth is `_Equal` ??), the [code would look like this](https://ideone.com/FSOMbN).

Comment: @WhozCraig living and learning, I liked the for like a foreach and I forgot the operator !=, thanks.