# Undefined reference when calling float array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am implementing a basic bucket sort algorithm.  The main.cpp file is the driving program, sort.h stores the function declarations and bs.cpp is the algorithm implementation.

main.cpp

```
case 0: bucketSort(arr, n); break;
```

sort.h

```
void bucketSort(int* arr, int n);
```

bs.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sort.h>

using namespace std;

// function to sort arr[] of size n using bucket sort
void bucketSort(float arr[], int n)
{
  vector<float> b[n];

  // put elements in different buckets
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    int x = n*arr[i];
    b[x].push_back(arr[i]);
  }

  // sort individual vectors
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    sort(b[i].begin(), b[i].end());
  }

  int index = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    while (!b[i].empty())
    {
      arr[index++] = *(b[i].begin());
      b[i].erase(b[i].begin());
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile, I receive error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `bucketSort(int*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.exe] Error 1
```

Not sure why it is coming back as undefined.

Comment: Look at what you have in `sort.h`, and look at your actual function. Keep staring at both, until you see the big, honking, glaring difference. You really don't see the two completely different function declaration and definition?

Comment: Side note unrelated to your problem: `b[n]` is not a good thing to do. Instead you should probably be using a nested `std::vector`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57367473/10957435 for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You forward declare `void bucketSort(int* arr, int n)` in `sort.h`, but you never define it. Rather, in `bs.cpp`, you define the function `void bucketSort(float*, int n)`.

Your code compiles fine, but the linker ultimately complains that it cannot find a suitable definition of `bucketSort`. You'll need to rectify the discrepancy between your declaration's signature and your attempted definition.